# Insert XML to MySQL db whilst making sure it is UTF8 and just in plain text (no symbols - é and such)

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I'm learning PHP or trying to by messing around with this small project.

I receive an XML weekly that I need to put into a mysql db, here's a small sample of what it looks like (It's usually a 35 children per Offer 50,000 Offer file.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<Offers>
    <Offer>
        <ProductName>10073482</ProductName>
        <Manufacturer>Random Brand</Manufacturer>
        <Description>Loerm ipsum....100-3000characters</Description>
        <ModelNumber>5191181</ModelNumber>
        <Price>29.99</Price>
    </Offer>
    <Offer>
        <ProductName>10073482</ProductName>
        <Manufacturer>Random Brand</Manufacturer>
        <Description>Loerm ipsum....100-3000characters</Description>
        <ModelNumber>5191181</ModelNumber>
        <Size>Large</Size>
        <Price>29.99</Price>
    </Offer>
</Offers>
```

I guess ideally I want to:

- import the XML make sure its all websafe
- make it UTF-8
- strip all symbols such as é
- find all the used fields per product
- make a table with that info
- force that massive XML into the table

After import I should have 48,000 items yet playing with different encode's like urlencode sometimes I get 26,000 and another time 52,000.

Here's what I've got so far: (Be gentle)

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors','On');
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);

    // Establish connection to database
    $con2 = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
    if (!$con2)  {  
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());  
    }
    $selectdb = mysql_select_db("f1", $con2);
    if (!$selectdb)  { 
        die('Database not used: ; ' . mysql_error());  
    }

    // Vars
    $name = $_GET['name'];
    $filename = $name . ".xml";
    $tableCreateQuery = "CREATE TABLE $name ( id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,";

    // Load XML
    if (file_exists($filename)) {
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($filename);

        foreach ($xml->children()->children() as $child){
            $currentAttrib = $child->getName();
            // Create query to create mysql table
            $tableCreateQuery .= " `$currentAttrib` TEXT,";
        }
        $tableCreateQuery = rtrim($tableCreateQuery, ",");
        $tableCreateQuery .= ") CHARACTER SET utf8";
        // Create mysql table
        mysql_query($tableCreateQuery);

        // Loop through adding XML to new mysql table
        $pCount = 0;
        foreach ($xml->children() as $child){
            $pCount++;

            $theColumnsArr = array();
            $theColumnsStr = "";

            $theDataArr = array();
            $theDataStr = "";

            $i = 0;
            foreach ($child->children() as $attrib){
                $attrName = $attrib->getName();

                $theColumnsArr[$i] = $attrName;
                $theDataArr[$i] = urlencode(utf8_encode($attrib));

                $i++;
            }

            $k = 0;
            foreach ($theColumnsArr as $value) {
                $colname = $theColumnsArr[$k];
                $coldata = $theDataArr[$k];

                $theColumnsStr .= "`$colname`,";
                $theDataStr .= "'$coldata',";

                $k++;
            }

            $theColumnsStr = rtrim($theColumnsStr, ",");
            $theDataStr = rtrim($theDataStr, ",");

            $theRow = "INSERT INTO $name ($theColumnsStr) VALUES ($theDataStr)";

            mysql_query($theRow) or die(mysql_error());

        }
        echo $pCount . " products added to database";

    } else {
        exit("Failed to open $filename");
    }

    mysql_close($con2);
?>
```

Comment: If you want to convert your non-utf8 data to utf8 data `$utf8_data = utf8_encode($data)` should do the trick. I assume you have already tried changing `$theDataArr[$i] = urlencode(utf8_encode($attrib));` to `$theDataArr[$i] = utf8_encode($attrib);`?

Comment: Yeah, I've used just `utf8_encode` but it still seems to fail importing a lot of the Offers, most the time its coming back with 26,000 ish Offers.
I did use
    `mysql_query("LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '$filename' INTO TABLE $name ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<Offer>';");`
previously and that imported the full amount of Offers but I couldn't manipulate the XML first with that.

Comment: Have you tried printing out your SQL statement and then executing it directly on your SQL server? Via phpmyadmin or so? eg. `echo $theRow` instead of `mysql_query($theRow) or die(mysql_error());` just to make your queries are all correct?

Comment: Yeah the queries look good, I think it's a case of invalid characters being in the data part of the query I've tried `htmlentities` on everything and even `urlencode` only to the same result.